# Retrieve Firebase data to label

Tags: ios, firebase

Im trying to retrieve firebase information and show it in a label.

```
// Get a reference to our posts
Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"**************firebaseio.com/"];

// Attach a block to read the data at our posts reference
[ref observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snap) {

  NSLog(@"%@", snap.value);

} withCancelBlock:^(NSError *error) {

NSLog(@"%@", error.description);

}];
```

I have tried adding in `_label.text = snap.value` but for some reason the app still keeps crashing.

I need to retrieve a load of information but for this test i just want to retrieve the only thing inside of the database. In the NSLOG i can see the value being retrieved from the database but cant seem to place the value in a label.

Comment: This is an easy fix but can you post your Firebase structure so we answer with code that matches your structure? Please post it as text (no images) and that can be gotten via the Firebase Dashboard->export button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the needed to be done was convert snapshot.value to a `NSString` then to a label.

```
Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"*************firebaseio.com/"];

[ref observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snap) {
    // do some stuff once

    //        NSLog(@"%@", snap.value);

    string1 = snap.value;


    _shown.text = string1;
    NSLog(@"%@", _shown.text);
```